# Why is my scoreboard showing a dash (-) instead of 0?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

On liroughriders.com website

At the end of a game I enter game results. If one of the team scores is a 0 then it shows a dash on the frontend of the website. All other numbers work and will show but if 0 is input then a dash is displayed instead. Any ideas why?

Thinking it might be a small fix since the other numbers show. I am using a capital O in the meantime to get around it. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Screenshot of scoreboard]

Comment: You may need to provide some code for us to investigate with.  Looking at the HTML, an actual `-` is listed, so it's not a javascript display.  My guess (and it's just that): something on the back end decided that a 0-0 score is a game that hasn't started yet, and is showing the special `-` to indicate to viewers no game has played.

Comment: Or another guess, it test if the score is false and then displays a dash, and because 0 is also false it shows a dash